# $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$ implies that $f(x)=0$ formal proof

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that if a function is such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ and also $f(0)=0$ then $f(x)=0$ for every $x$. I have an idea but it's too long, I want to know if there is a simple way to do it. Thanks!
Obviously in a formal way.

Comment: What about [that one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall's_inequality)?

Comment: I believe this is an exercise in Bartle.

Comment: Why don't you explain the idea you have?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An implicit assumption is that the function is defined on some open interval containing $0$. Set

$$g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$$

and compute the derivative:

$$g'(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f'(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f(x)=0$$

so the function $g$ is constant on the interval where it's defined. Since $g(0)=e^{-0}f(0)=0$ you can conclude that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ and therefore also $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

---

Without the initial assumption, you can get different functions with that property: define, for instance,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $-1<x<1$}\\
e^x & \text{if $2<x<3$}
\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ satisfies the requirements, but it's not constant.

Comment: Here $f(x)$ is not continuous so it is not differentiable hence no question of $f'=f$...

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu Are you really sure that the function $f$ in the counterexample is not continuous? I am sure it is. Please, state where the function is not continuous.

Comment: @egreg I guess it's a matter of casuistics, $f$ is left-continuous at $x=1$ but not right-continuous, since it does not exist. Usually   with standard definitions, we define continuiuty to be 2-sided.

Comment: @gt6989b $f$ is not even defined at $x=1$, so what? Would you say that $x\mapsto 1/x$ (defined for $x\ne0$) is *not continuous*?

Comment: I see. Still something tells me OP was looking for the functions defined on the entire real line, at least that's the way I read "for every $x$" - but I see how that could be interpreted differently.

Comment: @gt6989b I agree about OP's probable intentions. But the problem should be stated differently, saying explicitly that the function is defined on the whole real line. The final "for all $x$" means "for all $x$ where $f$ is defined" and the stated assumption merely require that $f$ is defined in an open neighborhood of $0$ (to ensure differentiability in the domain).

Comment: Sure, agree completely.

Comment: The is a special case of a uniqueness therem, essentially a Wronskian test for linear dependence - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

We can solve differential equation $f'(x)-f(x)=0$. It's linear differential equation with constant coefficient, and we know how to solve it. Setting $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ we obtain $\lambda e^{\lambda x} - e^{\lambda x}=0$, or $\lambda - 1 =0$, which implies $\lambda = 1$. So our solution is $f(x)=c e^x$. But, we have condition $f(0)=0$, so $c e^0=0 \implies c=0$, so our final solution is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: More direct version: let $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$. Then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f'(x)=0$, so $g=0$ and $f=0$.

Comment: @wj32 We had the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

Below I show how the standard proof (e.g. egreg's answer) is a special case of more general results on uniqueness theorems and Wronskians. Let's rewrite the proof in slightly more general form. Given that $\,f\,$ and $\,g = e^x\,$ are  solutions of $\,y' = y\,$ we deduce

$$\begin{eqnarray}\color{#c00}{f'=f}\\ \color{#0a0}{g'=g}\end{eqnarray}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \left(\dfrac{f}g\right)' = \dfrac{\color{#c00}{f'}g-f\color{#0a0}{g'}}{g^2} = \dfrac{\color{#c00}fg-f\color{#0a0}g}{g^2} = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\  \dfrac{f}g = c\ \ \rm constant$$

Therefore $\ f = cg = ce^x\ $ so $\ 0 = f(0) = c,\ $ thus $\, f = 0.\, $ This generalizes. The same proof shows that, assuming appropriate differentiability/continuity conditions, if $\,f,g\,$ are solutions of $\, y' = h y\,$ on an interval $\,I\,$ where the Wronskian $\,W(f,g) := f'g - fg' = 0\,$ on $\,I,\,$ then $\,f,g\,$ are linearly dependent on $\,I,\,$ i.e. $\,c_1 f = c_2 g \,$ on $\,I\,$ for some constants $\,c_i.\,$

Thus, by a very simple proof, we've deduce a *uniqueness theorem* for solutions of linear first-order differential equations of said type. These ideas extend to analogous higher-order linear differential equations. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320780/78535) for a proof of the second-order case (which generalizes to n'th order), using variation of parameters, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133673/78535) for the discrete analog of difference equations (recurrences). See also the classical result below on Wronskians and linear dependence.

**Theorem** $\ \ $  Suppose  $\rm\:f_1,\ldots,f_n\:$   are $\rm\:n-1\:$ times differentiable on interval $\rm\:I\subset \mathbb R\:$ 
and suppose they have Wronskian $\rm\: W(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\:$ vanishing at all points in $\rm\:I\:.\:$ Then  $\rm\:f_1,\ldots,f_n\:$  are linearly dependent on some *subinterval* of $\rm\:I\:.$

**Proof** $\ $ See [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58109/78535)

Comment: Seriously? If you want to hit it with differential equations why don't you use local lipchitz continuous? That would be 100 times easier?

Comment: @Dominic I edited the answer to make it clear that this simple proof requires no advanced knowledge - it can be understood by any calculus student. I mention more general uniqueness theorems for differential equations etc only to emphasize that this is a special case of more general results. I don't use these more general results in my proof. An important part of teaching is highlighting the relationships between concrete and general results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach, more suited for calculus students who do not know how to solve differential equations yet.

It's easy to prove by induction that since $f'=f$, the function $f$ must have derivatives of all orders and $f = f' = f'' = ...$ for all $x$, and hence $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = \ldots$.

Then, by Taylor's Theorem, we expand $f(x)$ in series around 0 to get

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \cdot 0
     = 0.
$$

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is expandable as its Taylor series?

Comment: @egreg Since it is infinitely differentiable at every point.

Comment: There exist functions that are infinitely diffentiable at every point, but aren't the sum of their Taylor series at every point; the classical example is $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @egreg You are right. I remember the problem from years ago as an exercise in Bartle *Elements of Real Analysis* - he did spend a serious effort trying to get rid of this problem, but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is continuous and infinitely differentiable:

- If $f(x) = f'(x)$, then: $f'(x) = f''(x)$, $f''(x) = f'''(x)$, et cetera.
- One function satisfies this property... Or rather, is defined by this property: $f(x) = A\,e^x$.
- $A$ can be determined by evaluating $f$ at $x=0$ such that $A = f(0)$.
- If $f(0) = 0$, then $A = 0$, therefore $f(x) = 0$ for any $x$.

In summary:

1. $f(x) = f^{\prime}(x) \rightarrow f(x) = A\,e^x$, or more generally $\lambda f(x) = f^{\prime}(x) \rightarrow f(x) = A\,e^{\,\lambda x}$
2. $f(0) = 0 \rightarrow A = 0$, or more generally, $f(k) = 0 \rightarrow A = 0$
3. $A = 0 \rightarrow f(x) = 0$