# proof of unique solution of particular differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $k$ is a given non zero constant show that the functions $y = c\operatorname{exp}(kx)$ are the only solutions of the differential equation
$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = ky$.
Hint: assume that $f(x)$  is a solution of the equation and show that $\dfrac{f(x)}{\operatorname{exp}(kx)}$ is a constant.
I tried to put $f(x)$ into the equation but I do not know how to proceed.
Please help.

Comment: It's convenient to write $\frac{f(x)}{\exp(kx)}$ as $f(x)e^{-kx}$. Now evaluate $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(f(x)e^{-kx})$.

Comment: See the proof in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/406828/78535)

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate $\frac{y}{e^{k x}}$ implicitly using the fact that $y'=k y$ and show that it is zero. Hence $\frac{y}{e^{k x}}$ must be some constant $A$ but this implies that $y=A e^{k x}$